# Blender 2.79 Windows 64Bit - Web-Cam starts on Start-up

Tags: system

I have a strange behavior, when I start-up the newest official Blender-release, my WebCam starts up. 
I cannot find any point. where to stop this. I guess, there's something "connected" to the start-up of Blender concerning "session-recording" for training-vid-production... I never had something like this.

Could please someon hlp me out of this?

Thanks
Greetings
Mike

Comment: What happens when you choose File, Load Factory Settings?

Comment: :-( Nothing. I also did a total de- and afterwards new-install...

Comment: Reinstalling doesn't reset your user preferences, so that wouldn't do anything. Do you have any add-ons enabled? By default Blender doesn't do any video recording at all. Where exactly did you download Blender from?

Comment: From the official Blender site. And there are no add-ons enabled, that aqre pointing to recordings....

Comment: I wouldn't make any assumptions, and just reset Blender to factory defaults (File → Load Factory Settings, File → Save User Preferences, restart Blender) to see what happens when all add-ons are disabled and preferences reset.

Comment: OOhh my Goood!!  I am sorry.. I found the issue. (I will write it also in the questions-section). I got meanwhile a new GraCard.. the Nvidia software installed a "Game-tracking"-feature. And obviously Blender was recognized as a "GAME!!"   .. I'll give detailed data on the thread...

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. It's really somewhat amusing:

I got and installed a new Graphics-Card on my system. (Geforce GTX 970)
The set-up also installed NVIDIA GeForce Experience (V. 3.10.0.95) and during install it set-up also "Game internal overlay", which basically opens the possibility for gamers to record videos of their game, the gamer himself, via WebCam and voices/sound.

The strange behavior is, that the Nvidia software recognizes Blender as a "Game" and switches on all the stuff. (I am not a gamer, so I never realized, that this is available at all)

After setting off this feature, everything turns back to normal.

Comment: Blender uses OpenGL to render its user interface, so in a sense it behaves like a game (3D viewport, with 2D stuff drawn over/around it).